# Is there a way to keep treasure locations on the map in New Game+?

Tags: tales-of-xillia, tales-of-xillia-2

When you find treasure in the field the location gets marked on your map so that you can easily find it later. Is there anything that allows you to bring these markers over into New Game+?

Comment: NG+ already?  Bleh, I'm nowhere near.

Comment: Haha. I was kind of rushing I guess. I didn't do any end game stuff. I would prefer to have the double exp/gald first and carried over merit points.

Comment: I like to make my first playthrough super thorough, and the second playthrough benefits from a ton of grade to spend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no way to transfer these markers across games.

You only need to find 800 unique random treasures (sparkles and white bags) in order to all associated titles in both games. Random Treasures in areas you only have access to once are not included in this count as mentioned [in this question.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/183739/do-random-treasure-points-in-fractured-dimensions-count-towards-your-records)