# Do random treasure points in fractured dimensions count towards your records?

Tags: tales-of-xillia-2

Treasure points are the sparkly points and bags found in the field of most non-town areas of the game and Treasure chests are the actual chests found all over.

You need to activate them for the titles "Loot Liker", "Loot Leige" and "Loot Lord" and the records "Treasure Found" and "Most Random Treasures Found".

Do the points found in fractured dimensions count towards your records of these things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they do not. Treasure points (the sparkly points and bags) and Treasure chests (the actual chests) found in fractured dimensions have absolutely no affect on your records. The only points and chests that count are those found in the main world.